# mysql command line utility ERROR 1406 (22001) on national characters

Tags: mysql

I ran a SQL script containing INSERT statements on a table that has sufficient column length using mysql command line utility and got an error:

*ERROR 1406 (22001) at line 115: Data too long for column 'Name' at row 1*

Note that same script works fine from MySQL Workbench. Statement that failed is:

*INSERT INTO `geotable` (`Id`,`Name`,`Description`,`IsReadOnly`,`IsActive`,`IsModified`,`LastUpdated`) VALUES (188,'Helsinki, Rovaniemi, Oulu, Kokkola, Jyväskylä, Por','',0,0,1,'2017-02-01 11:13:03');*

Like suggested in earlier posts, I tried with following and still doesn't work:

*SET @@global.sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'*

Server version: 5.7.20-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Windows Version 10

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`
replace with `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`